# Firefox JavaScript parameters passed to function are undefined on <audio> event

Tags: javascript, firefox, undefined

I see some questions previously asked on this topic but have either not been answered or I don't understand the answer.

Why does the following work in ALL browsers except FireFox? When the `onplay()` event fires, the parameter passed is `undefined`.

```
<html>
    <head><title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <audio id="audioplayer" name="player1" preload="none" onplay="audioStarted(audioplayer[0]);" src="http://kerkradio.co.za:8000/audio/beste-luisteraar.mp3?a=1" controls> </audio><br/>
        <audio id="audioplayer" name="player2" preload="none" onplay="audioStarted(audioplayer[1]);" src="http://kerkradio.co.za:8000/audio/beste-luisteraar.mp3?a=2" controls> </audio><br/>
        <audio id="audioplayer" name="player3" preload="none" onplay="audioStarted(audioplayer[2]);" src="http://kerkradio.co.za:8000/audio/beste-luisteraar.mp3?a=3" controls> </audio><br/>
        <audio id="audioplayer" name="player4" preload="none" onplay="audioStarted(audioplayer[3]);" src="http://kerkradio.co.za:8000/audio/beste-luisteraar.mp3?a=4" controls> </audio><br/>
    </body>

<script>
    function audioStarted(thePlayer) {alert(thePlayer.src);}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same `id`, which is invalid, and you're passing a variable that's undefined in the code you show, and you're trying to access a property of that variable. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi Thomas. I am aware of the multiple elements with the same name, hence passing the index counter i.e. audioplayer[0]. Works very well except in FireFox. 
Have a look at what I am really trying to accomplish here: [kerkradio.co.za](https://kerkradio.co.za)
The code example just simplified what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

That it works at all (which I guess it might) is an aberration brought about from javascript's weird hoisting of id's to the global scope (making getElementById oddly redundant). Firefox is quite right to cough this code back up, and I'd be surprised if it really were the case that it works in *all* other browsers

Try passing the keyword `this` instead of that audioplayer[n] jive - yours is the sort of situation that `this` was designed to handle